# Using Handler in DLL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll, handler

If I open ASP.NET, create a blank site, add a handler file, add a webform then on the webform add an image control and set the imageurl to handler.ashx, all works fine.

Open Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, create a class library project, delete the vb file that's created, add an ASP.NET handler and use the same code as in the above handler.ashx file, compile the code and then add a reference to that DLL from the asp.net project which copies the DLL to the bin folder. My question is, how to use that handler in the asp.net project?

Sure, in the web.config you can add to the hadlers section (not httphandlers) but if registering *.zzz as the extension and then in the imageurl of the image control. ex: "aaaaaa.zzz" it should return a jpg file because of the code in that handler but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a test app to replicate your issue and all works fine for me.
Here is a snippet of my handler configuration, compare it to what you have got:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="imageHandler" verb="*" path="*.zzz" type="CustomHandlers.ImageHandler, CustomHandlers"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

if this didn't work, please send the details of the error/exception you are getting.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replying! My config file is the same as the one you added above except for my class name is different of course and mine doesn't work. What am I doing incorrectly? There is no error. The imageurl says for example aaaaaa.zzz but the image is missing from the image control. That image is a captcha by the way. Exactly the same code in an ashx file works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to trigger a handler through a dll. What worked for me was using my handler on my local project, and then having the handler call a method from the class library project. That method can then contain all of the logic that is meant to be in your handler.